# Import-Csv, Sort Imported Data and Counting Total Variables after Sort

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to write a powershell script importing a large csv of data. I am trying to sort the objects column by date range and counting the objects in the column. I imported the data and assigned values however when I ask for the count of the total value in the columns it counts each individual object rather than the sum of the remaining. I believe this is because it's within the foreach cmdlet.

Any ideas? I am newer to powershell.

```
CSV format,
ID FirstName LastName Date
1   jOHN      SMITH    8/8/2016

$users=Import-Csv data.csv 

foreach ($user in $users) {

$FileID=$user.ID
$FileFIRST_NAME=$user.FIRST_NAME
$FileLAST_NAME=$user.LAST_NAME
$FileDATE=$user.DA

write-host $FileFIRST_NAME.count

}
```

Comment: in this case, I should have said I am just trying to get a count of the variables of each column to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the `foreach` loop (note that this is the `foreach` statement, not the cmdlet), each `$user` is a single row from within `$users` (which is an array of rows).

So asking for the `.Count` of any property (column) of a single row, will return `1`. The loop will run that `N` times where `N` is the number of rows you have, so you will see `1` many times.

You don't need the loop at all to get a count of the rows:

```
$users=Import-Csv data.csv 
$users.Count
```

Since columns are a property of rows in this scenario, a count of any column will be the same as the count of the number of rows, so there's no reason to do so.